# How to allow to edit a commited log message in only one directory in Subversion

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I have a repository with a dozen of projects.

I would like to allow to edit committed log messages just from one project (that where I work) for specific company policy questions.

Can I allow the edit just in one directory (and sub-directories recursively)? Or just for entire repository? If Yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write pre-revprop-change hook (not pre-commit hook as specified in question tags) and check that:

1. changed only svn:log message
2. all modified paths belong to project

if so - allow rev prop change.